# array sorting, but keeping other in sync

Tags: php

I have an array, like below. The fact is that `$array[0][0]` and `$array[1][0]` are connected. And should stay together.

But I would like to order on the `$array[1]` values.

```
$array[0][0] = '567';
$array[0][1] = '3971';
$array[0][2]  = '19';
$array[0][3] = '1';

$array[1][0]  = '10';
$array[1][1] = '50';
$array[1][2]  = '80';
$array[1][3] = '30';
```

So `$array[1][2]  = '80';` is the highest and should go to the top, but `$array[0][2]  = '19';` should move along in his own array.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

```
array_multisort($array[0], $array[1]);
```